# Trying to create a labeled numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to have a numpy array with values and corresponding labels for each value. I am using this array for linear regression and it will be my `X` data vector in the equation `y = Xb + error`.

My `X` vector consists of about 20 variables, each of which I would like to be able to reference by name like so `X['variable1']`. I was initially using a dictionary to do this but realized that the scikit library for linear regression requires a numpy matrix, so I am trying to build a numpy array that is labeled.

I keep getting an error stating:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'.
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
X = np.array([3],dtype=[('label1','int')])
```

I eventually want to have 20 labeled values, something like this:

```
X = np.array([3,40,7,2,...],
             dtype=[('label1',int'),('label2','int'),('label3','int')...])
```

Would really appreciate any help on the syntax here. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to create a structured array, with values, is with a list of tuples:

```
In [55]: X
Out[55]: 
array([(3,)], 
      dtype=[('label1', '<i4')])

In [56]: X=np.array([(3,4)],dtype=[('label1',int),('label2',int)])

In [57]: X
Out[57]: 
array([(3, 4)], 
      dtype=[('label1', '<i4'), ('label2', '<i4')])
```

But I should caution you that such array is not 2d (or matrix), it is 1d with fields:

```
In [58]: X.shape
Out[58]: (1,)

In [59]: X.dtype
Out[59]: dtype([('label1', '<i4'), ('label2', '<i4')])
```

And you can't do math across fields; `X*2` and `X.sum()` will produce errors.  Using `X` in an equation like `y = X*b + error` will be hopeless.

You are probably better off working with real 2d numeric arrays, and do the mapping between labels and column numbers in your head, or with a dictionary.

Or use Pandas.

Comment: Thanks, I went with your first approach and did something like: `keyValues = [('A',0), ('R',0), ('N',0)]`

Answer (score 0):

Since with 20 variables, memory is not an issue, you could keep on using dictionaries:

```
from collections import OrderedDict  # Dictionary that remembers insertion order
import numpy as np

dd = OrderedDict()
dd["Var1"] = 10
dd["Var2"] = 20
dd["Var3"] = 30

# make numpy array from dict:
xx = np.array([v for v in dd.values()])  

# make dict() from array:
xx2 = 2*xx
dd2 = OrderedDict((k, v) for (k,v) in zip(dd.keys(), xx2))
```