# How to resolve type errors while creating arrays with custom dtypes in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unicode

I am porting some code from python 2 to python 3. In my code, I define a data type for strings as:

```
MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 32
DT_WORD = np.dtype([('word', str('U') + str(MAX_WORD_LENGTH))])
```

Which shows up as:

```
>> DT_WORD.descr
[('word', '<U32')]
```

Now, when I create a basic numpy array, I get no errors:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    dtype='<U1')
```

But when I introduce my data type,

```
>> np.array(['a','b','c','d'], dtype=DT_WORD)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What does this error mean? All strings in python 3 are Unicode by default, so by explicitly stating the data type as Unicode I shouldn't get an error. How do I define my data type so it accepts unicode strings in both python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to eventually figure it out:

When using labelled `dtypes` the array is actually a *structured* array. Structured arrays arrays are created from a list of tuples (and not simply a list of values). So:

```
np.array(['a','b','c','d'], dtype=DT_WORD)
```

Should be:

```
np.array([('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)], dtype=DT_WORD)
```

More concisely, if `X` is a list of strings, you can use:

```
np.array(list(zip(X)), dtype=DT_WORD)
```

Which is compatible with python 2 and 3.

Also, the same code will give a `TypeError` in python 2 as well:

```
np.array(['a','b','c','d'], dtype=DT_WORD)
# Will give:
TypeError: expected a readable buffer
```

So my question was partly incorrect in the first place. It had less to do with python version than with the distinction between arrays and structured arrays.

Comment: Looks like `bytes like object` is the Py3 equivalent of a `readable buffer`.  I don't know why they don't give a better error message.  Trying to fill a structured array without the tuples must be a common enough error.

Comment: `np.array([b'ab', b'b', b'c'],dtype=[('word','U3')])` works; but the b'ab' is rendered as a chinese character.  https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object.  But why does a tuple work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532609/trying-to-create-a-labeled-numpy-array - I gave a similar answer here; but didn't dig further.