# Numpy Array using Dtypes Throwing Error

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing something fairly simple, I'm trying to convert a list of lists to an np.array:

```
rows = [[1, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0], 
        [2, 'None', 'None', 0, 0,    'None', 0, 0], 
        [3, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0], 
        [4, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0], 
        [5, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0]]

dtypes = np.dtype(
    [
        ('_ID', np.int),
        ('SOURCE_LILST', '|S1024'),
        ('PRI_SOURCE', '|S256'),
        ('PRI_SOURCE_CNT', np.int32),
        ('PRI_SOURCE_PER', np.float64),
        ('SEC_SOURCE', '|S256'),
        ('SEC_SOURCE_CNT', np.int32),
        ('SEC_SOURCE_PER', np.float64)
    ]
)
array = np.array(rows, dtypes) # error raised
```

Can anyone see what the issue it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `rows` object should be a list of tuples, not a list of lists:

```
rows = [(1, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0), 
        (2, 'None', 'None', 0, 0,    'None', 0, 0), 
        (3, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0), 
        (4, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0), 
        (5, 'None', 'None', 0, 0, 'None', 0, 0)]

dtypes = np.dtype(
    [
        ('_ID', np.int),
        ('SOURCE_LILST', '|S1024'),
        ('PRI_SOURCE', '|S256'),
        ('PRI_SOURCE_CNT', np.int32),
        ('PRI_SOURCE_PER', np.float64),
        ('SEC_SOURCE', '|S256'),
        ('SEC_SOURCE_CNT', np.int32),
        ('SEC_SOURCE_PER', np.float64)
    ]
)
array = np.array(rows, dtypes) # no error raised
```

---

A few extra hints:

1. Try to simplify your problem as much as possible to figure out where the issue is.  In this case, you could have deleted all but one of the columns, and hence `dtype`s, and still seen the problem.  This helps eliminate possible errors like whether or not you specified all those strings correctly, etc.
2. Google [your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532609/trying-to-create-a-labeled-numpy-array) before bothering to create a question.
3. When asking a question about why you're getting an error, include the error message — or at least some shortened version of it.

More generally, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's not just helpful for asking better questions, it's also a helpful way to figure out problems before you even get around to asking.